# how to use java eqaulsIgnoreCase() method

Tags: java

Am trying to use the IgnoreCase method in java

I want to write code that validates ID number like 292081811D13 but the when you enter lower case 'd' the results is false:

```java
import  java.util.*;

public class ValidateID{

    public static boolean validID(String idNumber){
        idNumber = idNumber.replaceAll("[^\\dABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTVWXYZ]", "");
        if(idNumber.length()!= 12 ){
            return false;
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++){
            if(!Character.isDigit(idNumber.charAt(i))){
                return false;
            }
        }
        int remainder = Integer.parseInt(idNumber.substring(0,9)) % 23;
        char expectedCheckLetter = "ABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXYZ".charAt(remainder-1);
        //idNumber.charAt(9).equalsIgnoreCase(expectedCheckLetter);

        if(Character.toUpperCase(idNumber.charAt(idNumber.length() - 3)) != expectedCheckLetter){
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter your ID number : ");
        String idNumber = scanner.nextLine();

        if(validID(idNumber)){  
            System.out.println("Your ID number is valid");
        } else {
            System.out.println("invalid ID");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you want that line to do?

Comment: to ignore lower case of the check letter on the ID number

Comment: and only the third to last character is relevant? Also, why are you not using `String#contains`?

Comment: how can i do that? I tried converting that Character to upper case but the output would be false

Comment: Learn how to format code in your Question. I fixed this code this time.

Comment: No, it sounds like you want to pay attention to lowercase, not ignore it. Your Question is poorly worded. Do you want to accept lowercase inputs or do you want to forbid lowercase inputs?

Comment: `equalsIgnoreCase()` is not defined for `char` – how does you code compile when you remove the commenting from the that line starting with `//idNumber.charAt(9) …`?

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this, you can convert both the actual check letter and the expected check letter to uppercase and then compare them. Here's the modified code:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ValidateID {

    public static boolean validID(String idNumber) {

        idNumber = idNumber.replaceAll("[^\\dABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTVWXYZ]", "");
        if (idNumber.length() != 12) {
            return false;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            if (!Character.isDigit(idNumber.charAt(i))) {
                return false;
            }
        }        
        int remainder = Integer.parseInt(idNumber.substring(0, 9)) % 23;
        char expectedCheckLetter = "ABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXYZ".charAt(remainder - 1);

        char actualCheckLetter = idNumber.charAt(idNumber.length() - 1);

        // Convert both letters to uppercase and compare them
        if (Character.toUpperCase(actualCheckLetter) != Character.toUpperCase(expectedCheckLetter)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter your ID number : ");
        String idNumber = scanner.nextLine();

        if (validID(idNumber)) {
            System.out.println("Your ID number is valid");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Invalid ID");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Opposite of `equalsIgnoreCase`

You asked about the [`String#equalsIgnoreCase`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#equalsIgnoreCase(java.lang.String)) method.

But your prose suggests that you want the opposite. You do not want to *ignore* [case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letter_case), you want to pay attention to case. You want to reject lowercase characters while accepting uppercase letters.

### Requirements

Your Question is unclear, but it seems you want to verify that the tenth of 12 characters of input is an uppercase Basic Latin letter (A-Z) while the rest are Basic Latin digits (0-9). (<-- Notice how simply a requirement can be stated.)

### Avoid `char`

Avoid using `char`, as that type has been essentially broken since Java 2 and legacy since Java 5. As a 16-bit value, `char` type is physically incapable of representing most characters.

### Code points

Instead, make a habit of using [Unicode code point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters) integers when working with individual characters.

### `switch` in modern Java

In modern Java, we can use a `switch` to test for a series of values. We want to loop on all the code points, and for each zero-based position number (an index) we check to see if that code point represents a digit or an uppercase letter.

### Example code (first draft)

```java
package work.basil.example;

public class ValidateId
{
    private static long EXPECTED_LENGTH = 12;

    public static boolean isValidId ( final String proposedId )
    {
        if ( ! ( proposedId.codePoints ( ).count ( ) == ValidateId.EXPECTED_LENGTH ) )
        {
            return false;
        }
        int[] codePoints = proposedId.codePoints ( ).toArray ( );
        for ( int index = 0 ; index < codePoints.length ; index++ )
        {
            int codePoint = codePoints[ index ];
            switch ( index )
            {
                case 0 , 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5 , 6 , 7 , 8 , 10 , 11 ->
                {
                    if ( ! Character.isDigit ( codePoint ) )
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
                case 9 ->
                {
                    if ( ! Character.isUpperCase ( codePoint ) )
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
                default -> throw new IllegalStateException ( "Unexpected index: " + index );
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Exercise that code:

```java
System.out.println ( "2x2081811D13" + " = " +  ValidateId.isValidId ( "2x2081811D13" ) );  // BAD: 2nd character (index 1) is a letter, not a digit.
System.out.println ( "292081811d13" + " = " +  ValidateId.isValidId ( "292081811d13" ) );  // BAD: 10th character (index 9) is lowercase.
System.out.println ( "292081811D13" + " = " +  ValidateId.isValidId ( "292081811D13" ) );  // GOOD.
```

When run:

```
2x2081811D13 = false
292081811d13 = false
292081811D13 = true
```

### Basic Latin

That code might be good enough. But that code is not perfect. That code ignores the [*Basic Latin*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_Latin_(Unicode_block)) restriction. Other characters beyond  Basic Latin can [also be a digit](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Nd/list.htm), and others can be an uppercase letter. So strictly speaking, we should check that all the code points are equal to or below 122, the code point for `z`. We can add a simple test near the top for that.

### Example code (second draft)

Also, we can replace the `!` at the front with `!=` in the test.

For brevity, we could collapse the `if` statements.

```java
package work.basil.example;

public class ValidateId
{
    private static long EXPECTED_LENGTH = 12;
    private static long LAST_CODE_POINT_OF_INTEREST = "z".codePointAt ( 0 ); // 122 = code point of `z`.

    public static boolean isValidId ( final String proposedId )
    {
        if ( proposedId.codePoints ( ).count ( ) != ValidateId.EXPECTED_LENGTH ) return false;
        if ( proposedId.codePoints ( ).filter ( ( int codePoint ) -> codePoint > LAST_CODE_POINT_OF_INTEREST ).count ( ) != 0 ) return false;
        int[] codePoints = proposedId.codePoints ( ).toArray ( );
        for ( int index = 0 ; index < codePoints.length ; index++ )
        {
            int codePoint = codePoints[ index ];
            switch ( index )
            {
                case 0 , 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5 , 6 , 7 , 8 , 10 , 11 ->
                {
                    if ( ! Character.isDigit ( codePoint ) ) return false;
                }
                case 9 ->
                {
                    if ( ! Character.isUpperCase ( codePoint ) ) return false;
                }
                default -> throw new IllegalStateException ( "Unexpected index: " + index );
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

We need to add another test. This extra test case has a THAI DIGIT ONE in the 2nd position. That character passes the `Character.isDigit` check, but will flunk our new check for any code points above 122.

```java
System.out.println ( "2x2081811D13" + " = " + ValidateId.isValidId ( "2x2081811D13" ) );  // BAD: 2nd character (index 1) is a letter, not a digit.
System.out.println ( "292081811d13" + " = " + ValidateId.isValidId ( "292081811d13" ) );  // BAD: 10th character (index 9) is lowercase.
System.out.println ( "2๑2081811D13" + " = " + ValidateId.isValidId ( "2๑2081811D13" ) );  // BAD: 2nd character (index 1) has a digit but is outside of Basic Latin: THAI DIGIT ONE.
System.out.println ( "292081811D13" + " = " + ValidateId.isValidId ( "292081811D13" ) );  // GOOD.
```

When run:

```
2x2081811D13 = false
292081811d13 = false
2๑2081811D13 = false
292081811D13 = true
```

Comment: i want output number 2 to be true as well as number 4

Comment: i want output number 2 to be true as well as number 4

Comment: @LawrenceMavhaire (a) Edit your Question for clarity. (b) So change the check from `isUppercase` to `isLetter`. Peruse the methods on `Character` class.

Answer (score 0):

To validate the **ID** string you may be able to use something simple like this (read comments in code):

```
public static boolean isValidID(String idNumber) { 
    /* Auto-Convert any lowercase alpha characters 
       (in this use-case, one) to uppercase:    */ 
    idNumber = idNumber.toUpperCase(); 
    /* Use the String#matches() method with a Regular Expression
       to validate the supplied ID string. It will return true if
       the ID string matches the regex or, false if not.      */
    return (idNumber.matches("^\\d{9}[A-Z]{1}\\d{2}$")); 
}
```

The [Regular Expression](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html) (regex) passed to the [String#matches()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_matches.htm) method does the following:

- `^` Asserts position at start of a line;
- `\\d{9}` Does the ID string start with **9** digits (each **digit** from **0** to **9**);
- `[A-Z]{1}` After the **9** digits is there a single (one) uppercase alpha letter character (**A** to **Z**);
- `\\d{2}` After the alpha character, are there two (2) more digits
  (each **digit** from **0** to **9**);
- `$` Asserts position at the end of a line.

The ID string conversion to uppercase should really be done before it is passed to the `isValidID()` method so that it is already modified before further use. If done this way, then *there is no need* for the conversion *within* the `isValidID()` method:

```
// Get ID:
String idNumber = "292081811d13";
idNumber = idNumber.toUpperCase();
if (!isValidID(idNumber) {
    System.out.println("ID is Invalid! (" + idNumber + ")");
    // return - exit - whatever
}
System.out.println("The supplied ID (" + idNumber + ") is Valid!");
```